# Perform count of documents mongo db after aggregation

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is my code:

```
 IAggregateFluent<MongoNavItemFilter> filteredData = _db.GetCollection<MongoNavItemFilter>("NavItemFilters").
            Aggregate().Match(query).Group(x => new
        {
            ItemID = x.ItemID,
            x.ItemWebCode,
            ...     
            ...    
            ...                        
        }, g => new
        {
            Key = g.Key              
        })
        .Project(x => new MongoNavItemFilter()
        {
            ItemID = x.Key.ItemID,
            ItemWebCode = x.Key.ItemWebCode,
            ...     
            ...    
            ...                 
        });
```

After this code I sort data and then permorm "skip-limit". But I need to get `Count` after `aggregation`. Could anyone explain me how? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the accumulator `sum` in your aggregate group. According to [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null) , it's a good way to count in aggregation and it's even more efficient than `count()` method if you have multiple database.

the syntax is basically :

```
{"sum", new BsonDocument {"$sum", 1}
```

But I'm use to `nodejs` or `java`, not C#. :/